# Web API , How to remove Slashes from web api json?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, backslash

Here is the Json Result :

```
"[{\"EmpId\":1,\"Full_Name\":\"Parth Dave\",\"City\":\"\"},{\"EmpId\":2,\"Full_Name\":\"Chirag\",\"City\":\"\"},{\"EmpId\":3,\"Full_Name\":\"Jay\",\"City\":\"\"}]"
```

Here is my code:

```
public string GetProducts()
{
    var empQuery = from emp in objEmployeeEntities.Employees
        select new EmployeeClass() { EmpId = emp.EmpId, Full_Name = emp.Full_Name };

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new NullToEmptyStringResolver() };
    var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(empQuery.ToList(), settings);

    return str;
}

public class NullToEmptyStringValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    PropertyInfo _MemberInfo;
    public NullToEmptyStringValueProvider(PropertyInfo memberInfo)
    {
        _MemberInfo = memberInfo;
    }

    public object GetValue(object target)
    {
        object result = _MemberInfo.GetValue(target);
        if (_MemberInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string) && result == null) result = "";
        return result;

    }

    public void SetValue(object target, object value)
    {
        _MemberInfo.SetValue(target, value);
    }
}
public class NullToEmptyStringResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        return type.GetProperties()
            .Select(p =>
            {
                var jp = base.CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization);
                jp.ValueProvider = new NullToEmptyStringValueProvider(p);
                return jp;
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use this method of `Newtonsoft`. `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("your-json-string-here")`. It will remove all `slashes(\)` from Json.

Comment: Tried that it says incorrect parameter error, ( for above given json string)

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava

Comment: So you don't say clearly, but this code is creating JSON from object, right? So in a string, the debugger shows `\"` for embedded quotes. So the question is, is this causing a problem on the client end, or do you just see the `\"` and are concerned?